# JavaScript/Node js import and export module(Using exported node Js module in JavaScript file)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to export node js modules to use in JavaScript. This is what I have done. 
-Installed esm in node.

in my node file I did like this:

```
require = require("esm")(module/*, options*/);

export function Myjs(name, surname){console.log(name, surname)};
```

This does not give error.
In my js file I did:

1- `import { Myjs } from '/javascripts/sockets/bases.js';` This gives error as "`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"`. I have been reading topics regarding this error, and it suggests that I should include "type: module" while including the file. But I do not include node js files as scripts on html.??

2- I try to import dynamically like this:

```
import('/javascripts/sockets/bases.js')
   .then((module) => {
      module.Myjs("bola", "carro");

  });
```

This gives error if detects require() in the file and it gives error "require is not defined" or any node js module that js does not recognize.??

What I'm trying to achieve is: Based on an event on js file trigger the function (`Myjs()`) I'm trying to import. How could achieve this? I tried babel and I wasn't successful. Thanks